# Dropzone.js with Spring MVC - file upload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, spring, dropzone.js

i am creating a html-based website with Spring MVC.
I have a upload function that works with the normal html input type=file.
Now i wanted to have a drag & drop function and tried to use dropzone.js.
I think that the problem is, that the dropzone doesn't pass the filepath to the html input type=file box. How can i achieve this? I want to use the dropzone only to get the filepath. The upload should still work with the form submition.

upload function in java:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, 
        @RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1, @RequestParam("file2")     MultipartFile file2)
        throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException {
    if (!file1.isEmpty() || !file2.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes1 = file1.getBytes();
        byte[] bytes2 = file2.getBytes();
        patientenService.uploadPDF(createdId, bytes1, bytes2);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("uploadfailed");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

dropzone in html-file:

```
<form class="dropzone" id="avatar-dropzone" method="post"
        action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <img id="dropzone-img" src="../image/01erstellen/arrow68.png" /> <input
            id="inputname" type="text" name="name" /> <input id="inputfile1"
            type="file" name="file1" /> <input id="inputfile2" type="file"
            name="file2" /> <input id="btn-abschicken" type="submit"
            value="Hochladen" />
    </form>
```

dropzone javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone($("#avatar-dropzone"), {url: "/file/post"});
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            paramName: "file1", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 10, // MB

    });
```

i hope that someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: Does the multipart file in the controller contain the file path, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating dropzone.js into existing html form with other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872417/integrating-dropzone-js-into-existing-html-form-with-other-fields)