# How to upload videos asynchronously using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave to upload movies to amazon s3. I want to do it asynchronously so that I can upload multiple videos at the same time and I want to use a progress bar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dropzone` for this. This is a sample code I have used in my app:

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag user_new_drag_drop_photo_path, method: :post, class: "dropzone form-horizontal", id: "media-dropzone", :authenticity_token => true do %>
  <div class="fallback">
    <%= file_field_tag "photo", multiple: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Js Code:**

```
function create_dropzone(thumbnailUrls){
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var mediaDropzone;
  mediaDropzone = new Dropzone("#media-dropzone", {
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    success: function(file, response) {
              $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.id);
              $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-success");
            },

    removedfile: function(file){
                  var id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id');
                  var parent = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').parent();
                  parent.remove();
                 // The above will remove the file preview but you can send a AJAX request to delete it from server
            },

    init: function () {
                // This callback be used to do some task on dropzone intialize
    }
  });
```

This is purely my code(I have deleted some part), you need to change it according to yourself. I have used `user_new_drag_drop_photo_path` this is my custom path you can take it to `photos_controllers` `create` action. It will send the request using `AJAX` and will save it through it.

More tutorial you can find here:

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: should it be a own form or can I use it in a normal form with other fileds as well?

Comment: You can do it on a separate `form` or instead you can do it on a `div`

Comment: how would it look like if I want to use it for a form file_field in my form?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872417/integrating-dropzone-js-into-existing-html-form-with-other-fields