# Upload text along with image through form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

Using dropzone.js i am trying to create drag and drop feature to upload images.

Code on form page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile))
      {
         $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name) VALUES('".$fileName."')");
      }
  }
?>
```

The above code uploads the image as soon as i drop the image, but i also wish to input following details in the form and on click of submit button it should get saved in database along with image

```
<input type="text" name="title"  value="Title" />
<textarea name="text" ></textarea>
<input type="text" name="email"  value="Email" />
<input type="submit" name="edit" alt="edit" value="Submit"/>
```

Can anyone tell how it can be done

Comment: Most likely it's a setting in your drag and drop that submits the file once it's been "dropped", you'll need to change that.

Comment: @Epodax yeah thats the part i wish to change, can you tell me how to do so

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  and `method="post"` into from element

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872417/integrating-dropzone-js-into-existing-html-form-with-other-fields]. This link may help you.

Comment: @user3732711 - did you try putting the other fields inside your `<form>`?

Comment: @Sachin K did that, still not working

Comment: @Logan Wayne yes i did that

Comment: @Vartika Shukla in the link you suggested, i tried 2nd solution, but in it i am not able to store data  in the database

Answer (score 0):

### Edited:

I'm requiring you to download jQuery first [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Then, we have to call it along side your `dropzone.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
```

You can include your other fields inside your form, or outside, not important with the path we will take later. Notice that we add `id` tags for your other input fields:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Title" />
    <textarea name="text" id="description"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email" id="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="edit" alt="edit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then, lets create a script for your dropzone and an Ajax which will run if the file you try to upload has met the requirements of your dropzone:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".dz-default").hide(200); /* THIS WILL HIDE FIRST THE UPLOAD FIELD */

    function insert(filename){ /* CREATE A FUNCTION THAT WILL INSERT THE DATA */

        /* GET THE INPUT DATA OF THE USER */
        var title = $("#this").val(),
            desc = $("#description").val(),
            email = $("#email").val();

        $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */
            url: "upload.php", /* FILE TO BE SUBMITTED THE DATA */
            type: "POST", /* METHOD TO PASS THE DATA */
            data: {'title': title, 'desc': desc, 'email': email, 'filename': filename} /* DATA TO BE PASSED TO upload.php */
        });
    }

    $(document).on("change keyup", "input", function(){ /* IF USER IS TRYING TO PUT DATA TO THE TEXT FIELDS */

        /* GET ALL USER'S INPUT */
        var title = $("#this").val(),
            desc = $("#description").val(),
            email = $("#email").val();

        if(title != '' && desc != '' && email != ''){ /* IF ALL INPUT HAS BEEN FILLED */
            $(".dz-default").show(200); /* SHOW THE UPLOAD FIELD */
        } else {
            $(".dz-default").hide(200); /* HIDE THE UPLOAD FIELD */
        }
    });

    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { /* WHEN USER UPLOAD A FILE */
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        accept: function(file, done) {
            insert(file.name); /* CALL OUR FUNCTION THAT INSERTS INPUT DATA WITH THE FILE NAME AS OUR PARAMETER */
        }
    };

});
```

Then for your `upload.php`:

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){ /* MOVE FILE TO YOUR PREFERRED DIRECTORY */

    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFile);

}

/* INSERT DATA TO YOUR DATABASE */
if(!empty($_POST["title"]) && !empty($_POST["desc"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["filename"])){

    /* USE AT LEAST REAL_ESCAPE_STRING BEFORE INSERTING THEM TO YOUR DATABASE */
    $title = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
    $desc = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["desc"]);
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $filename = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["filename"]);

    $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (title, description, email, file_name) VALUES('$title', '$desc', '$email', '$fileName')");

}
```

<strike>The only **problem** with this is that the user must put first their information before uploading the file.</strike> Made a solution by hiding first the upload field then will only show up after filling up all the text fields.

Comment: i tried that but as soon as the image is dropped,it saves the image path in database and on clicking on submit button redirects to another page but does not save the data

Comment: @user3732711 - check my updated answer. I put explanations along side the code I have provided.

Comment: @user3732711 - you have to read through my answer and understand it well before you can apply it properly to your work. Check for errors in your browser's console.

Comment: i am getting error ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined

Comment: @user3732711 - make sure they are all inside the `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid uploading image as soon as you drop the image, you can use following code.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(element, {
     url: "/upload.php",                        
     autoProcessQueue: false,
});

$('#imgsubbutt').click(function(){           
     myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

You can send extra data using "on sending" event.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {

  formData.append("text", "sample text");
});
```

OR you can save file on temporary location after drop. Then submit your form as usual. On server side file can be moved from temporary location to final location and then delete temporary location file.

Comment: still facing the same issue