# Error while implementing dropzone with laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I am having trouble integrating DROPZONE with form text on a system, using laravel 5.7.

I read the documentation but could not implement it.
reference: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

I read some tutorials like:
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone
https://jsfiddle.net/gued9y6m/
...
but none of them met my criteria

js file

```
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

// The configuration we've talked about above
 autoProcessQueue: false,
 uploadMultiple: true,
 parallelUploads: 100,
 maxFiles: 100,

 // The setting up of the dropzone
 init: function() {
 var myDropzone = this;

// First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});

// Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
// of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
  // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
  // Hide the success button or the complete form.
});
this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
  // Redirect user or notify of success.
});
this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
  // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
});
 }
 }
```

in form (blade.php)

```
   <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone">
   <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews 
    should be shown. -->

   <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
   <input type="email" name="username" />
   <input type="password" name="password" />

   <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
  </form>
```

What I would like:
The user must fill in all the form fields, add the photos and when I click "send all", an ajax request sends all the fields (including the photos) to a method in my controller, where it will be stored in the DB.

[What I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUZN0.png)

Comment: [You might try this question's answers for some ideas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872417/integrating-dropzone-js-into-existing-html-form-with-other-fields)

Comment: Hi @ourmandave,  i find the solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872417/integrating-dropzone-js-into-existing-html-form-with-other-fields.

thanks for your support,